# Inject test beans into main method

Tags: spring, command-line, spring-java-config

I'm using JavaConfig to manage and wire Spring beans into my Java app. The Java application is a main method - and basically runs as a batch job, invoked via a bash file. Is there a way that I can use a different (test) config in my main method?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
final ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
// do Stuff
}
```

I have used the following annotations successfully before in my test classes:
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfig.class })

, but this does not work for "main" applications. Short of passing in the Spring context to use as an argument, not sure what I can do here. Thanks

Comment: I am not entirely sure that I understand what you want to do here. But one simple way would be to parse a command line argument and change the class that you want to import based on that argument. I don't get what `@ContextConfiguration` brings here...

Comment: Check out Spring Boot. If I understand your requirement correctly, it should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use profiles in your actual config class to do what you want as well.
By setting the desired Profile you can "inject" the different beans you want.

Your ApplicationConfig might look like:

```
@Configuration
@Import({
    JndiDataConfig.class,
    TestDataConfig.class,
)
public class ApplicationConfig {
   ...
```

where TestDataConfig looks (in part) like:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class TestDataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
        .addScript("classpath:com/bank/config/sql/schema.sql")
        .addScript("classpath:com/bank/config/sql/test-data.sql")
        .build();
    }

}
```

and where JndiDataConfig looks like:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("production")
public class JndiDataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        return (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/datasource");
    }

}
```